# python - downscale output of pyplot.specgram

Tags: python, matplotlib, spectrogram

I have a 40 seconds recording, of which I plot the spectrogram with [`pyplot.specgram`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.specgram).
I want a vector graphics output out of it.

The output image is large, and when I include it in a PDF it makes it really slow to render. I would like to downscale it, but I don't know how.

I needed to do the same for a waveform, but that was easier because I could just downscale the input, and the waveform would look similar enough. If I downscale the input to the spectrogram, I imagine the frequency will change too, ruining the spectrogram.

How can I downscale the output of specgram maintaining the same input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you set the dpi on savefig(). I think that

```
savefig(filename, dpi=75)
```

or something around there should make it more manageable. . .

[savefig](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig)

Comment: I see, that's right. I had misunderstood the use of dpi. Since I'm show()ing the picture first, zooming on an area and then saving as PDF, do you know if it's possible to set the dpi on the output of that file? Many thanks.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Please mary the answer as accepted if that worked out for you!

Comment: I think that you can set a default dpi in a .matplotlibrc file that will be used for all saves.